# Login Once and Re-use access Token in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where we need to login once for given test users and re-use access token generated by loginscript for remaining API call for a duration of 1 hour.
One Approach which I think is to Login & write the tokens in csv file and then read these tokens from CSV file for executing remaining API's, but with
this approach we need to write token in CSV file in an agent.
Since, we will be running test in load test rig. we do not have access to write in agents.
Is there any approach using which we can Login once, generate token in some variable and re-use token.

Appreciate if any one can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login once for **each** user - put the logic for obtaining the token under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) and it will be executed during 1st iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Login once by 1 user and use the token by all users - put the logic for obtaining the token under [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test), save the token into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and read it in the main Thread Group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)